# when i click the button to update my form CSRF verification failed pop ups

Tags: python, django

I have two different forms in my index.html template and in both the forms i'm using csrf token.
The problem that i'm facing is when I try to update my form i'm getting "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." I've searched almost all the questions in this site and other websites and did everything still the error is shown.

This is my first form which adds student entry:

```
<form action = "{% url 'studentapp:addstudent' %}" id="addform" method = "POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "your_name">
                  Your name:
                </label>
                <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for = "course_name">
                  Course:
                </label>
                <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ current_course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
              </div>
              <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "rollno">
                  Roll No.:
                </label>
                <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ current_roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
              </div>
              <div class = "form-group">
                <label for ="addr">
                  Address:
                </label>
                <textarea id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ current_addr }}" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
              </div>
              <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
            </form>
```

This is my second form which is pre-populated when i click "edit" button on my template. when i click "update" button csrf token verification failed is displayed.

```
        <form action="{% url 'studentapp:editrow' rowid=id %}" id="editform" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "your_name">
              Your name:
            </label>
            <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ student_detail.name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for = "course_name">
              Course:
            </label>
            <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ student_detail.course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "rollno">
              Roll No.:
            </label>
            <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ student_detail.roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
            <label for ="addr">
              Address:
            </label>
            <input id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ student_detail.address }}" placeholder="Enter your address"/>
          </div>
          <input type = "submit" value="Update" id="update" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my ajax request:

```
function update_entry(id) {
  var id = id
  $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'studentapp:index' %}",
      type: "POST",
      data:{
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
          'id' : id,
      },
      success: function(response){
          $(".response").html(response.template)
          $("#editform").modal("show");
      }
  });
}

function update_property(id) {
  window.location.replace("/studentapp/editrow" + id+"/");
}
```

Comment: try to remove the second `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos I tried removing the second {% csrf_token %} still i got the error.

Comment: @Alasdair do i need to add the function on my script file?

Comment: If it's an ajax request that is failing, see the Django CSRF docs about [ajax requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: The snippet doesn't need to go in the script file, you can add it to your template. If you are sending form-encoded data then it's just a convenience. If you are sending json-encoded data then you must send the token as a header.

Comment: @Alasdair i've added my ajax request. can you check it?

Comment: I see you've ignored the suggesting in the docs to send the token as a header. Apart from that, I can't spot any problems with the `$.ajax()` call, although JavaScript isn't my strongpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using two separate forms, i was using two CSRF tokens. Removing one token was not solving the issue so I just did this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

in one of my forms and added these two lines in my index view:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    #Your Code
    csrf_token = request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
    response = {}
    response['status'] = False
    student_detail = #Your Model name

    context = {
        "Your dictionary"
        "csrf_token": csrf_token
    }
```

and it's working just fine for me.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this did not solve it. Which two line did you add. and how did you build your response?